# Laravel 5.1 optional route params in the middle of the URL

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

Is there any way I can use optional route params in the middle of the URL in Laravel 5. Here is what I want

```
Route::get('api/{locale?}/my-url', 'MyController@myAction');
```

Comment: one way is to have two routes one without {locale?} Route::get('api/my-url', 'MyController@myAction');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional parameter in the middle of a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584302/optional-parameter-in-the-middle-of-a-route)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have optional route parameters in the middle of the route path, because they make the definition ambiguous if they are omitted, and the route won't be matched.

---

You could have two route definitions one with and one without (as you've suggested in your comment):

```php
Route::get('api/{locale}/my-url', 'MyController@myAction');
Route::get('api//my-url', 'MyController@myAction');
```

But if you have lots of routes you'll have a lot of duplicates just for this.

---

You could just leave one definition with the locale, since there's no big deal of passing the default locale as part of the URL path. So if your default locale is `en` it just gets passed via the path as other locales:

```
http://example.com/api/en/my-url
```

---

However, since I'm guessing the locale is used for language appropriate responses and is only used for GET/HEAD requests, the best solution that I see here and it makes the most sense, is to just pass the locale as a parameter, because it's essentially an option:

```
http://example.com/api/my-url?locale=en
```

That way the Laravel route definition doesn't need to worry about it. Then you can use a middleware to change the locale if it is passed along in the query string. Here's an example of a middleware class that sets the locale and checks if it's an allowed locale:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLocale
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->has('locale') && $this->isValidLocale()) {
            app()->setLocale($request->input('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function isValidLocale()
    {
        return in_array(request()->input('locale'), ['en', 'es', 'fr', 'de']);
    }
}
```

Now in your controller action you can just use:

```
app()->getLocale();
```

And it will be set to the value passed in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well and you want the url to work both as `api/my-url` and `api/en/my-url` you can simply setup two routes:

```
Route::get('api/{locale}/my-url', 'MyController@myAction');
Route::get('api/my-url', 'MyController@myAction');
```