# How to use optional route parameters properly with Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to create an API with Laravel 5.6, however, it seems to me that it's not possible to use optional route parameters before/after the parameter.

I'd like to achieve the following:

```
Route::get('api/lists/{id?}/items', 
[
    'as'    => 'api/lists/items/get', 
    'uses'  => 'ListsController@getListItems'
]);
```

With the above scenario, if I'm trying to visit `api/lists/1/items` it shows the page. On the other hand, if I'm trying to visit `api/lists/items` it says that the page is not found.

What I basically want is if there's no List ID specified, Laravel should fetch all the List ID's items, otherwise it should only fetch the specific ID's items.

**Q:** How is it possible to the optional parameter in between the 'route words'? Is it even possible? Or is there an alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to use optional parameters in the middle of your url.

You could try a workaround by allowing 0 for the optional parameter and loading all items in this case, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584302/optional-parameter-in-the-middle-of-a-route).

However, I'd recommend going with two different routes here to match everything you want:

```
api/lists/items
api/lists/{id?}/items
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to give default value for optional parameter in the controller:

**Route**

```
Route::get('api/lists/{id?}/items', 'ListsController@getListItems');
```

**ListsController**

```
public function getListItems($id = null) {
    ---your code----
}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Comment: This solution is not working because the route is not even found.

Comment: This is not the solution because first of all laravel needs to find the route and /api/lists/items does not match with any of routes so it goes to 404 page