# Laravel optional parameter with slash in route

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble creating ONE laravel route that has an optional parameter.   The following achieves the behaviour I want:

```
Route::get('/{locale}/donate', 'MyController@index')->name('donation.index');
Route::get('/donate', 'MyController@index')->name('donation.index');
```

Both the urls `/fr/donate` and `/donate` will load the `MyController index()`.  However, when I do this:

```
Route::get('/{locale?}/donate', 'MyController@index')->name('donation.index');
```

The `/donate` will not load the `MyController index()`.  How do I make the `locale` argument an optional segment in the url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional parameter in the middle of a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584302/optional-parameter-in-the-middle-of-a-route)

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion there is no way to define the parameter as optional. Here are other ways to solve your problem.

**First**

```
Create a subdomain for that
```

**Second** move your optional parameter to the last. Now your route will look like this

```
Route::get('/donate/{locale?}', 'MyController@index')->name('donation.index');
```